# Can I check if domain is propagating

Tags: php, html, dns

Recently I've started working at a hosting company. Every day I have to check various domains, their nameservers, A records, and if they are currently propagating. That's why I decided to create my own website where I could check all the necessary information in one place (instead of using [DNSchecker](https://dnschecker.org/) or [WhatsMyDNS](https://www.whatsmydns.net/)) and learn more about the development of websites themselves.

Currently, I'm developing a simple website that would just show me the nameservers and the A records of the domain I entered. I was able to achieve that using **dns_get_record**.

Although, I can't be sure that the domain is not currently propagating. For example, in DNSchecker I can see the domain records from various DNS servers such as Google, Quad9, etc.

[image: screenshot of dnschecker]

Is there any way to see the records from various DNS servers on my website as well? Is there any way for me to see if the domain is currently propagating on my own website?

Hope I was clear with all of this!

Comment: Sure there is a way. You need to implement a collection of DNS servers, obviously. Then you can iterate over that collection and run your checks, list or sum up the results, whatever you like.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here at this stage because too theoretical/large without actual code. Also note that there is no propagation in DNS despite people calling it like that, since DNS is not top down but bottom up in resolution. As for "Is there any way to see the records from various DNS servers on my website as well?" you could start by querying big public resolver and see what they reply for your domain. Other than that you need your own DNS servers, so certainly not a first level kind of task.